# How do I fetch key values from a JSON model class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I am getting some API response in Swift for my application. So, I am saving that data into CoreData for entity and fetch too.

After fetching I am making model class for fetching data and I am passing it. So, I have to fetch that model class data and need to show it in a tableview cell as key values.

But, I am unable to fetch the model class, but I am able to pass data into the model class from database data.

Model class:

```
struct AccountInfoModel {
    var name: String?
    var birthdate: String?
    var age: String?

    init(dict: [String:AnyObject]) {
        self.name = dict[AccountinfoKeyConstant.Profile_name] as? String
        self.birthdate = dict[AccountinfoKeyConstant.Profile_Birthdate] as? String
        self.age = dict[AccountinfoKeyConstant.Profile_Age] as? String
    }
}

func fetchProfileData() {
    do {
        let profileData = try? Profile.fetchProfileInfo()
        if let profileInfo = profileData {
//            print("profileInfo \(profileInfo)")
            let profile = AccountInfoModel.init(dict: profileInfo as [String : AnyObject])
            print("profile \(profile)")
        }
```

How do I fetch data from the model class as key values to show in a tableview? Actually I have not worked with Swift much. Any suggestions?

Comment: so are you trying to parse through to find name, birthdate, and age?

Comment: Yes, I am passing database data to model class and I have to fetch that data into tableview cell as key values

Comment: is there a wrapper for the info? if so do you think you can supply that :)

Comment: I did not get you, I am new to swift, Earlier I worked with react native, Here how to fetch that model class data to tableview

Comment: im sorry for the miscommunication, for the .JSON file, is there a wrapper for the data points you are trying to get?

Comment: In regard to your previous question, why don't you fetch the record as `NSManagedObject` subclass instance. Then you get all information without key subscription, type cast and without mapping the data to something else.

Comment: Still I am learning Swift and coredata, Thank you @vadian for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by myself. I have just done model class initialisation and then passing data into model class.

After that I am constructing key values into some dictionary by passing model class data into some method.

```
    var accountInfoModel = [AccountInfoModel]()
func fetchProfileData() {
        do {
            let profileData = try? Profile.fetchProfileInfo()
            if let profileInfo = profileData {
                accountInfoModel =   [AccountInfoDBModel.init(dict: profileInfo as [String : AnyObject])]
                let data =  self.accountInfoModel[0]
                print("age is \(data.age)")

}
```

Now, It is working fine, I hope this will help someone.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have update my solution, I hope now its fine. Thank you

Comment: Fine, long term though I think you should take the comment from vadian into consideration.